# Preventing floating button to move on mobile when browser address bar hides

Tags: angularjs, mobile, angular-material

I developing a mobile website with angular-material which uses a floating button on the homepage as seen in many Google Applications. The button is always present and fixed in the right lower corner. It all works well. However, when I scroll the page and the browser address bar hides, the body height changes as well. The result is that the button moves up, too. See the images for better understanding.

[image]

This is the CSS of the button:

```
.floating-button{
    position: fixed; 
    margin-top: 120%; 
    margin-left: 80%;
}
```

When i use `top` instead of `margin-top`, the button moves up and once the address bar is hidden, it jumpes back down.

Is there any possibility that the button will stay fixed? I would prefer not forcing the address bar to hide or stay fixed. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```
.floating-button{
position: absolute; 
margin-top: 120%; 
margin-left: 80%;
```

}

Try using the position absolute rule instead. Position absolute keeps an element on the page where you specify it independent of other elements.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I came here with a similar problem and a combination of your question and what I already had solved my problem.

What I had is that the FAB would get hidden (move down) when the address bar is triggered and Kiko's answer didn't change that, so I assume it would bring my problem to your code.

For it to stop moving, I had to change my `position: absolute` to `fixed` like yours. The rest of the CSS is below:

```css
.floating-button {
  position: fixed;
  right: 20px;
  bottom: 20px;
}
```

I hope this helps future people passing by.